# Magento Quantity Discount by Percentage

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Are there percentage based quantity discounts?

I’m using Magento 1.8 and I want quantity discounts expressed as percentages.

I don’t see that in Magento. I know setting new Tier Prices but I want a Tier Price by a giving percentage.

For example, if someone buys 5 or more of Product X, I want to give them a 5% discount, If s/he buys 10 or more I want to give 10% discount....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Magento 1.6.2.0- and I can do this by creating a shopping cart rule for each tier of quantities.  see this page http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them

What I would do is create one rule for a percentage off of 5 or more, then an additional rule for an additional 5 percent off of 10 or more....and keep creating a rule for each tier

Comment: thank you for your response. This will help me I think.